# Definitive article usage

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I am not a 100% sure if article *the* is required in the following sentence:

> Unable to connect to *the* server

Could someone explain if it is required or not and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unable to connect to server", the version without the definite article, is ungrammatical.

However it's an example of the sort of terse language often used when time or space is limited, particularly in technical contexts, and so may be acceptable within that context.